# Find a point $Q_1$ on $L_1$ and a point $Q_2$ on $L_2$ so that $d(Q_1,Q_2) = d$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let **L1** be the line passing through the point **P1** = (−2, 3, 1) with direction vector **→d** = <−2, −1, −2>, and let **L2** be the line passing through the point **P2** = (4, 4, −4) with the same direction vector.
Find the shortest distance ***d*** between these two lines, and find a point **Q1** on **L1** and a point **Q2** on **L2** so that **d**(**Q1**,**Q2**) = ***d***.

**What I've solved for so far:**

**L1:** $<-2,3,1> + t<-2,-1,2>$

**L2:** $<4,4-4> + u<-2,-1,2>$

Consider a point $(-2,3,1)$ and a point on **L2** which is $<4-2u, 4-u, -4-2u>$

Distance between the points is:

d$^2$ = (-2u+6)$^2$ + (-u+1)$^2$ + (-2u-5)$^2$

I then differentiated both sides to get:

(4u-12) + (u-1) + (4u+10) = 0

u = $\frac13$

Shortest distance between the lines is then:

d$^2 = (-2(\frac13$)+6)$^2$ + (-($\frac13$)+1)$^2$ + (-2($\frac13$)-5)$^2$

d = $\sqrt{61}$

So I've gotten ***d*** to equal $\sqrt{61}$. I don't know where to go from here and solve for **Q1** and **Q2**.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines have the same direction vector, then they must be parallel.

So the plane perpendicular to line $P_1+td = (-2-2t, 3-t, 1-2t)$ will also be perpendicular to the line $P_2+ud = (4-2u, 4-u, -4-2u)$.

Since that plane passes through the point $$Q_1=(-2,3,1)$$ and is perpendicular to the direction $(2,1,2)$. Its equation is $2(x+2) +1(y-3) + 2(z-1) = 0$. Which simplifies to

$$2x+y+2z = -1$$

It will intersect the other line when $(4-2u)+(4-u)+2(-4-2u) = -1$, which is when 
$u = \dfrac 13$. This gives us the point $$Q_2 = \frac 13(10, 11, -14)$$. Then

$$d = \left \|(-2,3,1) - \frac 13(10, 11, -14) \right \| = \sqrt{61}$$